# Can a filter be an impure function?

Tags: angularjs

The following *works*:

```
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
.filter('myFilter', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return function(v) {
     return $rootScope.capitalize ? (v && v.toUpperCase()) : v;
  };
}])
.controller('myController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.flipCapitalize = function() {
    $rootScope.capitalize = !$rootScope.capitalize;
  }
}]);
</script>
{{"Hello" | myFilter }}

<div ng-controller="myController">
  <button ng-click="flipCapitalize()">flip</button>
</div>
```

The word "Hello" on the screen flips between mixed case and upper-case when you press the button.

But Angular doesn't "know" it is supposed to re-invoke the filter function.  It just does so because the click restarts the digest look and it re-does everything.

My question:  is that behavior guaranteed? Can I always assume that the filter will be reinvoked in the digest loop and I can use whatever data in any scope I can find?  Or did I just get lucky?

My secondary question: if the filter function is reinvoked on every digest loop, is there some way I can defeat that behavior?  Can I tell it, unless the arguments have changed, don't call this function again, you'll just get the same answer?  Or do I have to memoize by hand?

Comment: yes, 1st option would be run everytime, Instead of it I'd love to do it on angular directive which will update input on `keyup` event .you could do the second behavior using `ng-model-options`

Comment: Just as a side note, I would say that, in general, filters shouldn't be relying on state. Not saying there can't be exceptions, but it does feel wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter), if you want to guarantee your filter to work you need to mark it as "stateful" using the `$stateful` property of the filter.

> It is strongly discouraged to write filters that are stateful, because the execution of those can't be optimized by Angular, which often leads to performance issues. Many stateful filters can be converted into stateless filters just by exposing the hidden state as a model and turning it into an argument for the filter.
>
> If you however do need to write a stateful filter, you have to mark the filter as $stateful, which means that it will be executed one or more times during the each $digest cycle.

So you should mark your filter as stateful to guarantee that behavior:

```
.filter('myFilter', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  var filter = function(v) {
     return $rootScope.capitalize ? (v && v.toUpperCase()) : v;
  };
  filter.$stateful = true;
  return filter;
}])
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to make the model explicit between the filter and Angular without involving the client code at all?  I don't want to have to write `{{"Hello" | myFilter:capitalize }}` every single time, since capitalize is the only legal value (well, in my real case it is).

Comment: If you want it to be based on one global condition for your whole app, that's exactly the kind of thing `$stateful` is for. That might be the route you want despite warnings, because it sounds like you don't want to have to specify a parameter every time. The only suggested improvement I would have on your original code is using a service to get and set the global value instead of root scope.

Comment: The issue is, I have a _lot_ of uses of the filter and the global condition almost never changes.  Right now, I am using a directive that directly watches the condition, and I was thinking of switching to a filter, but it now sounds very expensive.